# C - Split a singly linked list with 'from' and 'to' index

Tags: c, struct, split, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I've recently come up against some problems regarding splitting a linked list with specific positions. Here is my required task:

> Write spitlist function:
>
> - Divide original list into 2 sublists.
> - splitlist(n1,n2) with n1 being the start position (count from 0) and n2 being the number of elements in sublist1. The rest is sublist2.

I've managed with one Split list exercise, which only requires sublist1 start from 0 position. Here is my code for this exercise:

```
void FrontBackSplit(struct Node* source, struct Node** frontRef, 
                struct Node** backRef)
{
int n; //length of node;

struct Node* current = source;

int pos; scanf("%d", &pos);
//position to split 
for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
    current = current->next;


*frontRef = source;
*backRef = current->next;
current->next = NULL;
}
```

But I have no idea how to solve the above-mentioned task. How to put all the remaining nodes into sublist2? Please help :(

Comment: `pos` is used uninitialized, and if if you iniitialize it to 0 you never enter the loop, what is `pos` supposed to contain?

Comment: Pos is the position where the List will be split

Comment: Ok, then you should check if `current->next` exists on each iteration, never trust users.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
struct Node* splitlist(struct Node* l, unsigned int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (l == NULL) return NULL;
        l = l->next;
    }
    if (l == NULL) return NULL;

    // Save head of new list
    struct Node* retval = l->next;

    // Break the list apart
    l->next = NULL;

    // return the new list
    return retval;
}
```

and call it like

```
struct Node* newList = splitlist(originalList, 42);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

int push_front( struct Node **head, int value )
{
    struct Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->value = value;
        new_node->next = *head;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( const struct Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->value );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

struct ListPair
{
    struct Node *head1;
    struct Node *head2;
};


struct ListPair split( struct Node **head, size_t pos, size_t n )
{
    struct ListPair p = { .head1 = NULL, .head2 = NULL };

    struct Node **current1 = &p.head1;
    struct Node **current2 = &p.head2;

    for ( size_t i = 0; *head != NULL && i != pos; i++ )
    {
        *current2 = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        ( *current2 )->next = NULL;
        current2 = &( *current2 )->next;
    }

    while ( *head != NULL && n-- )
    {
        *current1 = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        ( *current1 )->next = NULL;
        current1 = &( *current1 )->next;
    }

    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        *current2 = *head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        ( *current2 )->next = NULL;
        current2 = &( *current2 )->next;
    }

    return p;
}


int main(void) 
{
    const size_t N = 15;
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );  

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &head, rand() % N );
    }

    display( head );
    putchar( '\n' );

    struct ListPair p = split( &head, N / 3, N / 3  );

    display( head );
    display( p.head1 );
    display( p.head2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
7 -> 13 -> 6 -> 8 -> 11 -> 1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 10 -> 8 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 14 -> 9 -> null

null
1 -> 3 -> 3 -> 10 -> 8 -> null
7 -> 13 -> 6 -> 8 -> 11 -> 3 -> 1 -> 2 -> 14 -> 9 -> null
```

That is at first there is one list pointed to by the pointer `head`.

Then this list is split into two lists `p.head1` and `p.head2`. The list `p.head1`  gets `5` elements of the original list starting from the position equal to `5`.

All other elements are moved to the list `p.head2`.

As a result the original list is empty. Now all its elements are split between two lists `p.head1` and `p.head2`.

Comment: Thank you so much. However, If I have a linked list of struct type (in case of your code, "data" is a structure), how can I implement your algorithm? I can't seem to find a way :( All my trials failed

Comment: @htbi127 It does not depend on the fields of the structure. Just fill data members of your structure with required data. What is the problem?!